# Why does rabbitmq show 2 connections when I run a celery process?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have been playing with celery and rabbitmq for the handling of large image processing and am just trying to wrap my head around the fundamentals of how things work.

I have everything working fine, I am just not sure why things work the way they do which bugs me. The main thing puzzling me is that when I turn on a celery process

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

[image]

It runs fine and everything work, but when I look at the rabbitmq dashboard I am confused because it says that there are 2 connections. I am assuming that there is just something I don't understand. I could just overlook it and be fine with the fact that it is working, but I am just curious why when I run 1 celery process it makes 2 connections to rabbitmq. Maybe I am not understanding what a connection is.

[image]

[image]

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am using a hosted rabbitmq service and am not running this locally. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Even with `-c 1` option? `celery -A tasks worker -c 1 --loglevel=info`

Comment: It is still showing 2 connections with the -c option.

Comment: The defaults of [concurrency](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) is to the number of CPUs available on the machine.